# The ring $\ \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]\ $ where $\ \zeta \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{ 1 \} \ $ such that $ \ \zeta^3 = 1 \ $

Tags: ring-theory

Some exercise I have to make states that this is a ring. 
$$ \mathbb{Z}[\zeta] \ :=  \ \{a+b\zeta: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}  \} \qquad \text{where $\zeta^3=1$ and $\zeta\neq 1$}$$

I see that this is a ring with respect to "$+$", but I can't figure out why it's closed with respect to "$*$".

---

My problem is that it appears to me that $\zeta \cdot \zeta= \zeta^2$ can't be written in the form $a+b \zeta$. I see that $\zeta^2$ is a cube root as well, but $ 1<\zeta -\zeta^2 < 2$ or else $ 1<\zeta^2 -\zeta < 2$. I convinced myself about that by making a picture of the complex unit circle.

This means that the recquired expression $a+ b \zeta = \zeta^2$ does not exist.

I hope that some of you are familiar with this "ring" so that you can tell me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x^3 = 1$, then

$$x^3 - 1 = 0 \implies (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1) = 0$$

So $\zeta^2 + \zeta + 1 = 0$ gives a way to write $\zeta$ in the desired form.

---

On the complex plane, $\zeta$ is either $e^{i\pi/3}$ or $e^{-i\pi/3}$; in either case, it can be confirmed by direct computation that $\zeta^2 = -1-\zeta$.

Comment: Thank you. That was short, fast and clear.

Answer (score 0):

The three roots are $1, \zeta$, and $\zeta^2$. From Vieta, the sum of the roots must be zero.